# MYSQL Grouping by ID but pull based on latest Year

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the followings:

```
StudID  Name        Year    SubjectID   SubjectName             MTFlag
51280   ALOYSIUS    2019    42          CHINESE LANGUAGE        1
51280   ALOYSIUS    2020    70          ENGLISH LANGUAGE        0
51280   ALOYSIUS    2020    95          CHINESE B               1
51280   ALOYSIUS    2020    75          MATHEMATICS             0
51290   AMIL        2020    70          ENGLISH LANGUAGE        0
51290   AMIL        2020    85          MALAY LANGUAGE          1
51290   AMIL        2020    75          MATHEMATICS             0
51290   AMIL        2019    59          MALAY LANGUAGE          1
```

I need a query such that it will group by StudID, Locate for Subject that has MTFlag=1 and show the SubjectID and SubjectName based on the latest Year.

So the end result should only show:

> ```
> 51280 ALOYSIUS    2020    95          CHINESE B               1
> 51290 AMIL        2020    85          MALAY LANGUAGE          1
> ```

Appreciate the help.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did the group by StudID, and able to filter by MTFlag but don't know how to pull only the latest Year info:   select StudID, max(Name) as Name, max(Year) as Year, max(case MTFlag=1 then SubjectID end) as SubjectID, max(case MTFlag=1 then SubjectName end) as SubjectName from Table group by StudID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL 8+

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       StudID,
       Name,
       MAX(Year) OVER (PARTITION BY StudID) Year,
       FIRST_VALUE(SubjectID) OVER (PARTITION BY StudID ORDER BY Year DESC) SubjectID,
       FIRST_VALUE(SubjectName) OVER (PARTITION BY StudID ORDER BY Year DESC) SubjectName,
       1 MTFlag
FROM test
WHERE MTFlag;
```

For MySQL 5.x

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT t2.StudID, MAX(t2.Year) Year
               FROM test t2
               WHERE t2.MTFlag 
               GROUP BY 1 ) t3
WHERE t1.MTFlag
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99164511a422d7756caec990b13258b3)